# jquery.scrollify.js short content section

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-scrollify

I'm using https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify (jquery.scrollify.js) to handle my page scrolling. By default the plugin sets the section height to 100% window height and expand the height, if the content is bigger(x-axis) than 100% window height.

But what I need is a smaller section (not 100% height). Second color on the picture below.

[image]

Greetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add interstitialSection to the config and add the classes you don't want to have full height.

```
 jQuery.scrollify({
    interstitialSection: ".header,.small-section",
    ...
```